# Ask for stream-based decompression

Tags: compression

I'm working on object storage. One of the hard things is: due to the large volumn, files are compressed before they get stored within gcs/s3.

The current fetching method is:

1. read all content into a buffer, could be ~500MB
2. decompressor(whichever) decompress it
3. following steps, which includes a serialization into a protobuf

I'm thinking, whether it's possible to decompress while reading from cloud?
Eg: the total size stored on cloud is 500MB, everytime I receive 20bytes, and decompress it.

Comment: What is the compression method and format? Most compression methods support both streaming compression and streaming decompression.

Comment: @Mark Adler like lz4, gzip, snappy

Comment: Actually I'm curious how decompressor supports stream-based decompression? Eg: some compressor may write metadata at the beginning of the result. What if the metadata is not read over in the input string?

Comment: "like"? You don't know how your files were compressed?

Comment: There're compressed in multiple ways

Comment: All of the ones you mentioned stream. We can't help you with how, unless you provide some basic information like the compression method, the programming language, and the platform.